# Scan through multiple ranges and store unique value pairs into an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to scan through two columns (one which is formatted to text and the other column is a custom format; not sure if this matters, but just in case) and I want to write a snippet of VBA to have this array only contain unique pairs.

[image]

I hope to cycle through the table in order to compare each element of the table with the unique values of this array so that I can perform some sorting operation.

The end result should be

```
ScanArray = Array("Per SA","Per SB", "Per SC", "Per FC", "Mod SC", "Mod SB", "Mod SA", "Mod FC", "SP SA", "SP SB", "SP SC", "SP FC")
```

...with spaces to separate out the two distinct elements

My code below for trying to intake two ranges into my array - but it's not working as I had hoped...

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub ArrayFill()

 Dim WkSht1 As Worksheet
 Dim ScanArray As Variant
 Dim k As Integer

 Set WkSht1 = Worksheets("Cashflow")
 'the compiler definitely doesn't like this
 ScanArray = WkSht1.Range("C3", Range("D36")).RemoveDuplicates 

 For k = LBound(ScanArray) To UBound(ScanArray)

'Do Until Something
    'If matching function Then
    'MsgBox ScanArray(k)
    'End If
'Loop
Next k

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you-

```
Option Explicit

Sub ArrayFill()
    'Populates the array in the format as specified by the question
    Dim WkSht1, tmpSht As Worksheet
    Dim ScanArray() As String
    Dim i, iCntr, lRow, n As Long

    Set WkSht1 = Worksheets("Cashflow")
    n = WkSht1.Range("C1" , WkSht1.Range("C1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    ReDim ScanArray(n-1)
    For i = 1 To n
        ScanArray(i-1) = WkSht1.Cells(i,3).Value & " " & WkSht1.Cells(i,4).Value
    Next i

    'Removes duplicate entries from the array
    Set tmpSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    For iCntr = 0 To UBound(ScanArray)
        tmpSht.Cells(iCntr + 1, 1).Value = ScanArray(iCntr)
    Next
    tmpSht.Columns(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
    lRow = tmpSht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    ReDim ScanArray(lRow-1)
    For iCntr = 0 To UBound(ScanArray)
        ScanArray(iCntr) = tmpSht.Cells(iCntr + 1, 1).Value
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    tmpSht.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. One question - what was the reason for ReDim ScanArray(n-1)? If I am not careful at starting the n variable at a point in the columns that picks up data - then it seems like ScanArray(n-1) will also pick up the column header names which I didn't want. Not questioning your skill as much as I am just trying to understand the reasoning.

Comment: @GordonKing You have got a good question. Actually, `ReDim ScanArray(X)` resizes **ScanArray** to store **X+1** values and so to store **X** values, we need to write `ReDim ScanArray(X-1)` **or** `ReDim ScanArray(1 To X)`. Please read the documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - apologies my reply wasn't as timely. I read more into ReDim or re-dimensionalizing my arrays and the context in which I am understanding it in is if we declared an array of static length (i.e. `Dim array(5) As Double`). Problem for my understanding here is that we simply declared an array `ScanArray() As String` - I am assuming is telling the computer to dynamically allocate memory for ScanArray() by default. Perhaps I am wrong and that is the need to ReDim in your code?